# Ad failed to load : 0 and Interstitial ad failed to load

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

This is my first-time using AdMob which I implemented, and I am getting this issue. I am unable to load interstitial ads. Of course, I am using test ads. I also linked my test device in AdMob. Only once I was able to see ads. 'Only once. Then I also tried using real ads but I still didn't work

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device SM G615F...
Restarted application in 2,425ms.
D/ViewRootImpl@82b0554[MainActivity](15191): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@82b0554[MainActivity](15191): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
I/flutter (15191): london
I/Ads     (15191): This request is sent from a test device.
I/Ads     (15191): Ad failed to load : 0
I/System.out(15191): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(15191): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/flutter (15191): Interstitial ad failed to load
```

Comment: Please refer to error code list https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603/admob-error-codes-logs?hl=en

Comment: Now I am able to see test ads but only one time. Do we see test ads only one time in ad mob

Comment: have you tried this link? Make sure app is linked as per documentation https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10564477?hl=en

Comment: Yes, I did. But my test ads are also not working.  And there can't be errors in the code because at least once test ads work. So, this made me sure that codes are fine!!

Comment: If your app is newly created then give it some time, also make sure app is linked in app store in order to view correct advertisements.

Comment: Okay, Since I haven't yet published it. So, I do it maybe after that problem will be solved.